# SQL - Manage duplicates using hierarchy

Tags: sql, duplicates, hierarchy

Consider the following table.

| Customer | Category | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ajax | VIP | 1A |
| Zeus | Retail | 2B |
| Hera | Retail | 3C |
| Ajax | Retail | 1A |

Notice the duplicate 1A value, which is both VIP and Retail.

How to manage these duplicates using a hierarchy, where if VIP, then keep VIP and remove retail ?

End result should be

| Customer | Category | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ajax | VIP | 1A |
| Zeus | Retail | 2B |
| Hera | Retail | 3C |

Thanks

I've tried assigning values as such:

VIP = 100
Retail = 1

Then group by Key and summing the new column. If results are within a specific range (>100) then the customer gets assigned VIP, otherwise Retail. In the end, original Category column is removed, replaced by Computed_Category.

Looking for a more elegant method.

Edit:

There are 17 categories, with each superseding those below in rank.

Example here

SELECT
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTNUMBER ORDER BY
CASE
WHEN CLASS = 'X' THEN 1
WHEN CLASS = 'Y' THEN 2
ELSE 3 END, UNIQUEID) RN
FROM (VALUES        (100,'AA','Z')
, (200,'BB','X')
, (300,'CC','X')
, (400,'DD','Y')
, (100,'AA','Y')
, (100,'AA','X')
) t1 (CUSTNUMBER, UNIQUEID, CLASS)

ORDER BY UNIQUEID, CLASS

End result should remove 100-AA-Y and 100-AA-Z.

If a category is not found, use the next one in the hierarchy.

Comment: By using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY and assigning a specific rownumber to each category (17 in total), I managed to use a WHERE RN = X statement to filter on particular Category. However this is not different from having a WHERE CATEGORY = 'A' OR 'B', thus this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is there 17 different categories for each customer? if so, what should be returned when there are multiple categories for a customer but none of them is VIP?

Comment: There are a total of 17 categories. Customer Ajax can be VIP, Retail, Corporate, etc.
If Ajax is flagged once as VIP, it supersedes any other category, and thus the table should only contain AJAX - VIP 1A. The current situation is that the data is fussy, and AJAX is both VIP and Retail. In a way, I should built a hierarchy where VIP > Corporate > Retail > etc.

Comment: And what if there is a duplicate with no VIP category, which category should be selected in this case? or there is no such case

Comment: OK, I think I got it, you want to select first VIP, if not existed VIP select Corporate, if not existed Corporate select Retail and so on, right?

Comment: Example data : 
SELECT 
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTNUMBER ORDER BY
                   CASE
                   WHEN CLASS = 'X' THEN 1
                   WHEN CLASS = 'Y' THEN 2
                   ELSE 3 END, UNIQUEID) RN
  FROM (VALUES        (100,'AA','Z')
                    , (200,'BB','X')
                     , (300,'CC','X')
                     , (400,'DD','Y')
                     , (100,'AA','Y')
                     , (100,'AA','X')
       ) t1 (CUSTNUMBER, UNIQUEID, CLASS)

ORDER BY UNIQUEID, CLASS

Result should only have 100-AA-X for CUSTNUMBER 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use row_number function with order by case expression as the following:

```
Select Customer, Category, Key_
From
(
  Select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Customer Order By 
                         Case When Category = 'VIP' Then 1 
                              When Category = 'Corporate' Then 2
                              When Category = 'Retail' Then 3
                              -- continue for all categoreis 
                              Else 17 
                          End, key_) rn
  From table_name
) T
Where rn = 1
```

If you could have a separate table that holds each category and it's priority, you may simplify the query as the following:

```
Create table Categories(Category VARCHAR(50), priority INT);
Insert Into Categories Values 
  ('VIP', 1),
  ('Corporate', 2),
  ('Retail', 3); -- list all categories
```

And the query:

```
Select Customer, Category, Key_
From
(
  Select T.Customer, T.Category, T.Key_,
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By T.Customer Order By C.priority, T.key_) rn
  From table_name T LEFT JOIN Categories C
  ON T.Category = C.Category
) T
Where rn = 1
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LyPAs0C6).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement but failed. Editing my original question to reflect this.

Comment: According to your posted description and sample data this query works, could you show me a case where it fails, you could use this fiddle edit the sample data run it and share the new link. https://dbfiddle.uk/LyPAs0C6

Comment: Found the issue, it was due to the database (Snowflake). Creation of priority rank table and join solved my issue. Thanks a lot.